# Convert Negative to Positive Based on Another Column in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I have some data that is negative and I need to convert it to a positive but it has to be based on another column.

So this is what I have:

```
each if ([Column1]< 0 and [Column2] = "X") then [Column1] *-1 else [Column1] *1)
```

But I can't get it to work. Column1 is the values and Column 2 is the one with the text.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to change the value of Column1 as needed

```
  let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
  Flip =  Table.ReplaceValue(Source,  each [Column1], each if [Column1]<0 and [Column2]="X"  then -[Column1] else [Column1] ,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column1"})
  in Flip
```

If you just want another, 3rd column, then add column, custom column, with formula

```
=  if [Column1]<0 and [Column2]="X"  then -[Column1] else [Column1]
```

[image]

Comment: So are you saying I need to have two tables to do this? I can't just have a new column created for it? Sorry still learning PowerQuery little confused.

Comment: The first is sample code to replace the contents of Column1. The second is sample code to just add a 3rd column instead. Paste the first into home ... advanced editor.... with the sample data, and for the second, follow the instructions.

Comment: The second one did it! I think I had the X not caps correctly